# Locate worksheet from user input

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with numerous pages, named "Assessment 1, Assessment 2,..." etc. What I am trying to do is for a user to enter *only* the number of the assessment so that a different worksheet can reference the values contained in assessment *x*. Any suggestions welcome.

I don't have any "proper" code but I am defining the input variable as a string.

Thanks!

Update: I'm using the below code;
Dim input as string
input=Inputbox("Enter assessment no:")

Trying to get excel to pick up the string and read to assessment X is the issue. e.g.: input is 3, I want excel to reference data from the sheet named "Assessment # 3".

Comment: How do you handle user input? Do you need a formula or a VBA function to return the worksheet object from its full or partial name?

Comment: Look into the `INDIRECT` function which allows for arbitrary user input to be used to define a range.